# Typeahead in the templates empty function - event doesn't work(Knockout.js)

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, typeahead.js, knockout-3.0

I would like to add the custom event in the empty function from empty results.

Here is an example code.

```
 ,templates: {empty: 'No results' + '<a data-bind="click: event">Go</a>', suggestion:... }
```

When I click the GO event, it doesn't work.

Let me know if you have any suggestions.
Thank you.

Comment: it doesnt work because when you run "ko.applyBindings(model)" the data-bind is not in the html dom yet. I will close as duplicate here you find answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27137834/knockout-components-not-binding-on-new-content

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Knockout components (not) binding on new content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27137834/knockout-components-not-binding-on-new-content)